# Search file with multiple extension c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have some files that have multiple extensions(ex: D*.P*.C*) I'm building a process to move files with specific extensions like the above one and .csv and .arc files. I'm failing to filter D*.P*.C* files. Here is the code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var entries =
    Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(_sourceLocation_FRUD, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(s => (s.StartsWith("D"))
                          && (s.Contains(".P"))
                          && (s.EndsWith(".C")));
```

Comment: Do the file names contain anything after `.C` or should they end with it?

Comment: Please provide example of what you want and what you get.

Comment: `s.StartsWith("D")) && (s.Contains(".P"))` looks OK, but `EndsWith(".C")` won't match with anything that has chars after the `.C`.

Comment: @Ghasan It contains some random numbers after .C

Comment: @DeanOC I tried changing (s.Contains(".C")) still it's not picking the files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter isn't Regex, but it is a form of [wildcard search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3eayw32(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Remove the LINQ code and specify your extension pattern in the method call. Since the `*` means 0 or more characters, you should be able to just use your `D*.P*.C*` pattern.

```
var entries =
    Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(_sourceLocation_FRUD, "D*.P*.C*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Assuming only the extension starts with `D`, not the full filename, you may have to change your pattern to `*.D*.P*.C*`

Comment: I have other extension files to filter in too so i couldn't use this

Comment: Still I can have one more statement to pick these files too like you said. Thanks much @Grant Winney